# How to send notification based on role?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

How to send notification based on role. For example if I have 5 different roles I select only one role then that role people should get notifications using FCM and remaining role should not get for this. Do we need to write service in back-end(using SPRING,PHP)?

Comment: Are you trying to ask on 'How to send notification based on role'?

Comment: Do you use firebase database? Or you have your own databases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to [subscribe each client to a topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging#subscribe_the_client_app_to_a_topic) based on their role. For example in the Android app:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("myRole");
```

Then you [can send a message to all users in a role with the Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#send_to_a_topic) with:

```
admin.messaging().sendToTopic("myRole", { 
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "great match!",
      "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark"
    }
})
```

A few things to note:

- Sending a message to devices requires that you specify the FCM Server Key. As its name implies, this key should only be used on a server or another environment that you control. The Admin SDK runs with full credentials, so automatically has access to the FCM server key.
- Anyone can subscribe to any topic. So in the above example, malicious coders could also subscribe themselves to topics of roles they are not part of. If this is a concern for your app, you should not use topics but instead maintain your own server-side mapping of FCM registration tokens to roles. This [example from the Cloud Functions documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens) is a good place to get started with such a custom mapping